# Jquery Ajax - Handling application level errors

Tags: jquery, ajax, exception

I'm specifically using Jquerys .post() method to submit ajax calls, and receiving them as a json encoded.

```
    function createUserAccount() {
        $.post( "createUserAccount", $( "#UserAccountForm" ).serialize(), function() {

        })
            .done(function(data) {
                parseddata = JSON.parse(data); 
                // Do Stuff
              })
            .fail(function() {
                alert( "There was a problem with the Ajax call" );
              })
            .always(function() {
                alert( "Always" );
        });
    }
```

What is the recommended way of handling application level errors (example: username is already taken. The user of this form then know that the ajax call failed (From an application perspective) and needs to change his proposed username.

Should I be putting something in the JSON return, to mark the ajax call as a success or failure from the applications perspective? If so, do we have any code examples? How do we do this?

Note I'm not talking about HTTP level status codes, I understand those are on a level below my application custom errors and emssages.

Comment: The way I handle such cases are to use a combination of http error status + proper error message returned in the response as a json message

Comment: like if there was a validation failure then return a `400 Bad Request` with a response like `{"message": "First Name is mandatory"}`

Answer (score 1):

I prefer setting a success in the json, or return an error message. I reserve throwing exceptions to truly unexpected failures, like no contact with the database.

Answer (score 0):

You're treading into unfriendly territory here, as this can be somewhat controversial :) There are many opinions on how to do error handling in responses, and I'll try and be mostly objective here.

The primary way that I've seen it done is exactly as you said: to put something in the response. This will usually involve a success: true|false and a message field.

Another, probably less common, way is to be non-verbose about errors and simple return an empty or false json object.

Lastly, there's response codes. This is ... technically the "standard" way to do it, and that would be to return a response header. Don't. Honestly, just don't.

I'd recommend using the first option, since it seems you are going for verbosity, plus it lets you do very standardize error checking of "succes == true?"